# Multi-level CSS3 Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

As the title implies, I'm looking to create a full-fledged multi-level dropdown menu with CSS. I haven't the slightest clue as to how to begin. I've progressed a bit only to fully tangle bits of code with each other. I'm barely starting out and would appreciate any assistance to better understand how it operates. I understand applying it for the first

---

The CSS is included in the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ks5SL/

---

HTML

```
<body class="body">
    <header class="main-header">
        <img src="#" alt="Logo">

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main 2</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-left"><a href="#">Main 3</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-right">Sub 1</li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 3/a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-right">Sub 2</li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 3/a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </ul>
                <li class="dropdown-left"><a href="#">Main 4</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-right">Sub 1</li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 3/a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-right">Sub 2</li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Multi 3/a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Main 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="maincontent">
        <div class="content">
            <article class="topcontent">
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#">Welcome</a></h2>
                </header>

                <footer>
                    <p class="subheader">This is under title of content</p>
                </footer>

                <div class="articlecontent">
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequunt</p>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequunt</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="bottomcontent">
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#">Title of Content</a></h2>
                </header>

                <footer>
                    <p class="subheader">This is under title of content</p>
                </footer>

                <div class="articlecontent">
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequunt</p>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequunt</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>

    <aside class="topsidebar">
        <article>
                <img src="" alt="QR Code" style="display: block; margin: auto;">
        </article>
    </aside>

    <aside class="middlesidebar">
        <article>
            <h2>Middle Sidebar</h2>
            <p>asdgfauisdg oisdaoisdfoia sdfoasfasfsf ufi iufdfia ioudsf oidoiusdf dsf as </p>
        </article>
    </aside>

    <footer class="mainfooter">
        <p>Copyright information, etc.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: In my book, "Functional CSS," the last case deals with that very problem.  The chapter focuses on building a multi-level dropdown menu that is displayed in four different ways depending on the screen size.  The menu is built using positioning, flexbox, and media queries.  You are welcome to check it out on amazon.

Answer (score 0):

It's late, so short explanation and example - hope it helps :)

You do not enclose your sub childs to parent menu...

It should be like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">main</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**Example**

HTML CODE:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 1</a>
        <ul>                                      
            <li><a href="#">sub 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub sub 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#menu{
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
}


#menu > li{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    line-height:20px;
}

#menu a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px 10px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu li ul{
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left:0;
   min-width:150px;
   background-color:silver;
}

#menu ul ul{
    top:0;
    left:150px;               
}

#menu li li a:hover{
   background:red;
}

#menu li ul{
    display: none;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6SDma/